Can I use "circleci tests run" to split and run the MATLAB test cases?
I can run and split MATLAB tests using the circleci tests split command. Can I do the same using a circleci tests run command so that I can leverage the benefit of rerunning failed tests provided by this command? I wanted to try something like below:
        - run:
          name: Execute CircleCI Tests Glob Command in MATLAB
          command: |
             cd tests
             circleci tests glob "**/*.m" | circleci tests run --command "xargs matlab -batch runtests" --split-by=timings  

But the problem here is it is not splitting the MATLAB files.
